# Yanking into register within a script is not working

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode, register

Given a file like this:

```
Roy
Maurice
Jen
Douglas
```

If I were to type the following commands: `ggVj"zy`, followed by `:reg z`, I would see **Roy** and **Maurice**.

Now I want to yank **Jen** and **Douglas** into the `z` register, but by a different method. If I do: `GVk:normal! "zy<CR>` *(where <CR> is a key press of the Enter key, of course)*, the `z` register remains unchanged. Even erasing the `'<,'>` range modifiers after typing `:` doesn't help.

The above is an easy way to show the problem. I'm implementing it in a function that I call with a `vnoremap` key mapping:

```
function! Foo()
    reg z       " show before
    normal! "zy
    reg z       " show after
endfunction
```

So why is my `normal! "zy` statement not working? Is there something I've missed or misunderstood?

Comment: Side note, you could also use `:[range]yank z`. If you have a range, it could be `:'<,'>y z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something I've missed or misunderstood?

Yes, there's no `y` command in Normal mode. It's `y{motion}`.

As your command ends prematurely it simply does nothing.

Comment: Of course - Visual vs Normal mode. It looks like I'll have to investigate the range modifier in my function definition. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @PhilR you can just reenter visual mode using `normal! gv`

Comment: @PhilR Usually, it's easier to start Visual-mode mapping with `"zy` and only then call a function. But if you really must do it the other way round, you have `normal! gv"zy`, as @Mass suggested, or `'<,'>yank z` if you support only linewise selections.

Comment: @Mass, @Matt Thanks for the suggestions. The `gv` command is what I need in my situation. I don't want to limit myself to linewise selections, and my function is taking the precaution of saving and restoring the contents of `@z` when it's done.